# People wake on spaceship, computer lies to each person, he/she was the only survivor

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I've seen a trailer not too many weeks ago where the things described in the title happened. It was a mainly white spaceship with a computer which told everyone who woke up, he/she was the only survivor on the ship.

They soon find other "survivors" and wonder why the computer lied.

I firstly thought, this was "Dark Matter", but the respective trailers don't contain any AI computer.

So, does anyone know where this is from? It's a relatively new sci-fy series.

Comment: Maybe not in the trailers, but Dark Matter does have an AI aboard the ship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, just found it again. It was "Continuum" what I meant... well, not as "new" as I thought though.

Comment: That's not Continuum!

Comment: "It's Continuum, Jim, but not as we know it"  ;-) http://watchcontinuum.com You'd think they could have thought up a different title